# Blocked loading mixed active content - NoIP with github pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, github-pages, noip

I have a server running on an AWS instance, and I access it using a No-IP address.

The address given by No-IP is an http one but ,because my Front-end is located on github pages, it seems to only supports https...

Any way of authorizing mixed-content or deactivating https in github pages ?

Comment: I was trying to help someone with this same problem today. Still looking.